# Is it possible to set a cost alert within a daily grain on Google Cloud Platform (GCP)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, devops

Let's suppose that I have a resource group which has a daily average cost of $300, then I want to set an alert when the cost of this resource group reach $320 in a day. Is it possible to do that alert set for a daily analysis?

Answer (score 1):

Sure that is possible,
First of all, in GCP there is no "Resource Group" this is for Azure, but you have most of the components at the project level.

These types of alerts are the budget alerts, you can check how to set them here: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets

Basically, you can set alerts or create also policies to restrict the amount used in each of your projects.

Comment: Hi, I check the document and it says "You can specify the time period for the budget, configuring budgets for monthly, quarterly, yearly, or custom time ranges." It seems that it is hard to detect "single day high cost" event. Correct me if I am wrong.